# Is it safe to place part of texmf-local under git?

Tags: revision-control, texmf, git

Are there any problems with placing parts (or all) of texmf-local under [Git](http://git-scm.com/) source control? Git places a hidden directory in the folders it manages. Are there issues caused by doing this; would doing so bother any of the TeX configuration tools.

Comment: no there are no implications. I use that method.

Comment: @zeroth: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: I tried to elaborate a bit more about what could also be done in another situation. I dont know your intentions of use, so I added a bit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there are no implications. I belive the only files that will be searched for by the list generation tool is the files listed in the output of running:

`kpsewhich --help`, and then look under:
**Recognized format names and their (abbreviations) and suffixes:**.

None of these are defaulted in the `.git` folder (unless you add them to your script directory).

And even so it only searches files in certain sub-directories under for example `tex`.

Even though this does not pose any problem I generally like to have things separated, and have thus created a new folder to which I link by `ln` down to `texmf-local`. This enables one to quick-switch between different package versions if this it what you had in mind?

If it is a purely managing package versions on several machines and not *real* version controlling, what you had in mind is deemed appropriate.